# css3 animation does not start with jquery click event

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have two div tags which are card 1 and card 2. When user clicks on card 2 then card 2 should scale down and card 1 should scale up. I am doing this using css3 transformation and jquery click event. The problem is it does not start that animation at all. Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Humu3/)

Here is my code

```
.card {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: lightblue;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 3s;
}
.card2 {
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: orange;
    transition: all 3s;
}
.scaleUp {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
.scaleDown {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fiddle check this http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/Humu3/27/
you can modify it your according and check the code below
**css**

```
.card {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: lightblue;
    transition: all 3s;
    visibility:hidden;
    width: 100px;
}
.card2 {
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: orange;
    transition: all 3s;
}
.scaleUp {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);/*Safari 5+, Chrome 10+*/
    -ms-transform: scale(2); /*Internet Exlorer 9+*/
    transform: scale(2);
}
.scaleDown {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.50);/*Safari 5+, Chrome 10+*/
    -ms-transform: scale(0.50); /*Internet Exlorer 9+*/
    transform: scale(0.50);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.card2').click(function () {
    $('.card').css({visibility:'visible'}).addClass('scaleUp');
    $(this).addClass('scaleDown');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
card = $('.card');
card2 = $('.card2');

card2.on('click', function () {
    card2.removeClass('scaleUp').addClass('scaleDown');
    card.removeClass('scaleDown').addClass('scaleUp');
});

card.on('click', function() {
    card.removeClass('scaleUp').addClass('scaleDown');
    card2.removeClass('scaleDown').addClass('scaleUp');
});
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.card {
    width: 0px; 
    height: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: lightblue;
}
.card2 {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: orange;
}
.scaleUp {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 3s;
}
.scaleDown {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 3s;
}
```

Here's a fiddle where you can try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/tkahn/Humu3/21/

Comment: I want the first card should be invisible at first and when user clicks on second card. The second card will scale down and become invisible whereas the first card will become visible by scaling up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method, using [jQuery `.animate();`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Humu3/34/)**

```
$('.card2').click(function () {
    $('.card').animate({
        width: '200',
        height: '200',
        fontSize: '100%',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 500, function () {});
    $('.card2').animate({
        width: '0',
        height: '0',
        fontSize: '0%',
        opacity: '0'
    }, 500, function () {});

    $('.card').click(function () {
        $('.card2').animate({
            width: '200',
            height: '200',
            fontSize: '100%',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 500, function () {});
        $('.card').animate({
            width: '0',
            height: '0',
            fontSize: '0%',
            opacity: '0'
        }, 500, function () {});
    });
});
```

This method offers a few advantages:

- It should degrade gracefully for older browsers, opacity may be lost but scaling will still work.
- The text inside div will scale/hide along with the div.
- Borders will be hidden along with the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) to accomplish this. It works in most browsers and performs well on mobile devices too:

```
//set card initial state
$('.card2').css({ scale: 0 });

$('.card').on('click', function () 
{
    $('.card2').transition({ scale: 1 }, 3000);
    $('.card').transition({ scale: 0 }, 3000);
});

$('.card2').on('click', function () 
{
    $('.card2').transition({ scale: 0 }, 3000);
    $('.card').transition({ scale: 1 }, 3000);
});
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheGAFF/fBEqR/)